# How to restrict the ImageView mask layer movement in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, mask, uipangesturerecognizer

I have applied the clipping mask effect (using the MaskImage + OriginalImage = Clipping mask effect image).

[image]

I set the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView`

The problem is I want to move the image alone not the mask image.

Comment: how did you solved this issue ,pls share some code,trying to solve problem to many days

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use hitTest to pass touches, but also wanna to know the details